# How to use LDA as an input feature into another classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, text-classification, lda

I used LDA (Latent Dirichlet Allocation) in topic modeling on text dataset. I need the LDA result (for each instance) as an input into another ML classifier (SVM)
any idea how to add it?

I tried embedding the LDA result with BoW features but didn't work
here's the error I get:

`ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [5, 10103]`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The way to provide LDA output as features would be to give the vector of probabilities 'topic given document' (i.e. vector of size the number of topics) for every document.